# I'm trying to build an Quiz App Where the user Defines the Amount of QA but the loop fails and doesn't reach the specified amount given by user

Tags: java, android, loops

Fair Warning: I'm a student trying to build an app for our research.

So I'm Trying to build an app where the user Defines the amount of Q/A he/she wants, then the app will ask for the user to put different Q/A until it reaches the an equal amount where it will then open up a new page to make the user answer those Q/A.

The Problem is that the Loop fails to repeat at the stated amount by user making the app not being able to store let's say 10 Q/A to the JShared / Shared Preference.

Here's the loop code:

```
package com.prgr.quizards.canary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

public class question extends Activity {

    private HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    private TextView text;
    private EditText inop;
    private TextInputEditText ans;
    private AppCompatButton btn;
    private SharedPreferences jshared2;

    private SharedPreferences jshared;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
        initializedata();
        AppCompatButton btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(v -> gotoback());
        btn.setOnClickListener(view -> logicg());

    }
    public void gotoback(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(question.this, activity_home_screen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void initializedata(){
        jshared = getSharedPreferences("j", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        jshared2 = getSharedPreferences("j2", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        inop = findViewById(R.id.inop);
        ans = findViewById(R.id.ans);
        text = findViewById(R.id.text1);


    }
    private void logicg() {
        String mount = jshared.getString("amount", "");
        int amounts = Integer.parseInt(mount);

        for (int i = 1; i < amounts; i++) {
            //String shite = Integer.toString(qloop);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), shite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (i == amounts) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(question.this, answerscrn.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else{
                map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("answer", Objects.requireNonNull(ans.getText()).toString());
                map.put("question", inop.getText().toString());
                jshared2.edit().putString("data", new Gson().toJson(map)).commit();

            }


        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do a `for loop + if else` inside the for loop and that only returns the error of `Condition 'i == amounts' is always 'false'` what i expect is for it to loop till it reaches the same number stated by the `amounts` (which is the user defined value) to open up a new page using intent.

Comment: So the user makes his own questions first? Or what am i missing? `where the user inputs Question and answer,`

Comment: yup the user makes his own questions with the answer first before it opens up a new page which then the questions will be asked.

here's the flow:

User Inputs "10" as the amount of questions --> Moves to new page --> New Page Requires User to put the questions and answer depending on the amount stated by user --> if the questions reaches 10 and is equal to the user input amount it will then open up a new page to ask those questions made by the user.

sorry for the bad interpretation of the question

Comment: `yup the user makes his own questions` AND `User Inputs "10" as the amount of questions` IS SOMETHINGH COMPLETELY DIFFERENT. I understand now the user is NOT making his own questions but just chooses some questions. Please change the subject of your post and the text of your post as you suggect the user its making is own questions which is not the case.

Comment: no no you don't understand.  The user has to define the amount of question he want's to have in the app. once it's defined the application will perform a loop in which the app requires the person to enter questions and answer until it reaches the amount stated by the person. and when that amount got reached it will then move to another page where the questions will be asked. if you still don't get it i can record the app in it's unstable form and send it here.

Comment: To make things clear you can find `amounts` as a Jshared, this Jshared is where the value from the previous page is stored which is "10". now as you can see in the For Loop you'll find that `amounts` is stated there `for (int i = 1; i < amounts; i++)` and inside this loop is where the whole thing begins. it will ask the user to put their own question and answer. the loop will be performed each time the user puts an the QA once the value of `i` in loop reaches 10 and is equal to `amounts` it then will open up a new page that will be the quiz part that utilizes the information given by user

Comment: `no no you don't understand. The user has to define the amount of question he want's ` That i understood already but in the subject of your post you stil talk about that the user inputs the questions... which means that the user writes the questions. Also in your post you suggest writing by user. Please adapt your post. Write a better post.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your problem it in the loop, tho I don't understand how do you ask/put diffrent questions.

**i == amounts** is never true because the condition in the FOR loop is: **i < amounts**

You can simplify your code like this:

private void logicg() {

```
    String mount = jshared.getString("amount", "");
    int amounts = Integer.parseInt(mount);

    for (int i = 0; i < amounts; i++) {
        //String shite = Integer.toString(qloop);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), shite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("answer", Objects.requireNonNull(ans.getText()).toString());
        map.put("question", inop.getText().toString());
     
        jshared2.edit().putString("data", new Gson().toJson(map)).commit();

        
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(question.this, answerscrn.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I will try this and tell you the result. A friend of mine suggested using map to store the data in Jshared. which then utilizes the Shared Preference of the app to store all the questions.

Comment: Ok the loop somehow works but it goes up to only 5 when i stated that it will go upto 10

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 1; i < amounts; i++) IF THIS WAS YOUR LOOP AND YOU TOLD THAT USE WILL SELECT THE NO OF QUESTION SO
IF YOU ADD THIS LOOP THEN YOUR APP WILL STOP AT -1 STEP FOR EXAMPLE
IF YOUR USER SELECT 10 AND THIS LOOP WILL END AT IT WILL END AT 9
BECAUSE YOUR APP IS STARTING AT I=1 AND I<AMOUNT (THE VALUE ENTER BY THE USE SO YOU CAN MEET THE GOAL
SO YOU NEED TO CHANGE THE LOOP TO  for (int i = 1; i < =amounts; i++)

Comment: this worked but for some reason my app always reports "9" when i hit the start button then after it adds 1 more it then will open up the intent